# Table View not matching full screen

Tags: java, android, uitableview, android-layout, center

I have designed an activity layout, in the layout I have two separate tables next to one another. The problem is that the the tables are not displayed proportionately on the screen.

[image]

**If you notice the screen shot, you will see that the left margin of the table is not the same as the right one. What should I do to make the tables appear in the center of the screen?**

The **xml layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".ReportListActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/srno_table"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
                </TableLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1" >
                <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/report_table"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


                    </TableLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where am I going wrong? What should I do to achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the padding top,right ,left

Comment: @vsk its all the same, moreover, the table got stuck in the top left corner, its not centered at all...........

Comment: try with margin right and left as 6dp

Comment: @vsk the left gap is less and the right is more

Comment: @vsk more or less similar to the given pic

Comment: Add `android:stretchColumns="*"` to both `TableLayouts`.

Comment: @Luksprog then only the first table is taking up the full screen, the second one is not showing up

Comment: Can you try adding `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to the `RelativeLayout` child of `ScrollView`(the gravity property is useless there if you use wrap_content for width/height)?

Comment: @Luksprog cheeres dude! It worked!